# Android animate view outside fragment is getting clipped

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a view in a fragment. This fragment is within a FrameLayout. I want to animate this view moving outside the fragment borders. However, the view always get clipped when crossing the border. I have tried by setting `android:clipChildren="false"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"` to everything, but I can't get it to work.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: any luck with this? How are you adding the fragment; dynamically or via layout? I'm adding dynamically, and then animate a view inside it, which gets clipped. Can't get it to now clip; found this while looking for work around. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the similar problem with fragments and put `android:clipChildren="false"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"` on all the levels in my hierarchy, but it was still not working. The trick that worked for me was to add this override in my fragment code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
    vg.setClipChildren(false);
    vg.setClipToPadding(false);
}
```

Hope this helps...

P.S. the credit should go to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21926522/951745)

Comment: The idea behind this solution, or at least how I understood it, is that when you use fragments there are views that the system creates for you to hold it, and that view was the weak point since it was the only one which I was not seeing from xml or code or anywhere else. And this solution is actually giving the access to this "last view standing" which doesn't have setClip...(false) called on it. I believe that is why it worked for me.

Comment: Given this, my advice would be for you to try to dump the view hierarchy at run time at the point when everything, all the views and fragments are created and shown, and dump the clipping flags of all the views in this hierarchy. In my case I removed the rest setClip...(false) which I added all over the place "just in case" and it still works, just found the best place to put it. In your case you can set all of them and check if still doesn't work when all are set. P.S. forgot to say that if you are talking about Android 2.x then forget about it - I didn't manage to make it work on it :)

Answer (score 2):

frangulyan You're missing the other bit of code from your credited answer.  The below solution worked for me.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    //This can be done in XML
    rootView.setClipChildren(false);
    rootView.setClipToPadding(false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
//This is the NoSaveStateFrameLayout - force it to not clip
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) getView();
frameLayout.setClipChildren(false);
frameLayout.setClipToPadding(false);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The answers already given by @frangulyan and @Barrie Galitzky were both on the right track, but I had to add this loop to setClipping false for all parents in the hierarchy before it would work properly

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
    while(vg != null) {
        vg.setClipChildren(false);
        vg.setClipToPadding(false);
        vg = vg.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup ? (ViewGroup) vg.getParent() : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, and correct answers have been given, but I wanted to add that you can do the same thing as frangulyan does inside `onCreateView` using the `ViewGroup`. I.e.:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    container.setClipChildren(false);
    container.setClipToPadding(false);
    // Whatever other setup you like
    return View;
}
```