# ViewPager seems to reenable clipChildren when scrolling if PageTransformer is set

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with both clipToPadding and clipChildren set to false. The items in the pager have a drop shadow effect that is drawn below each item, outside of its bounds. This works just fine when the pager is static:

[image]

However, when animating between pages the children are clipped just as if clipChildren has been set:

[image]

The behaviour only occurs when the PageTransformer is set.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After digging around for quite a while i found the following post here on Stack overflow: [Do not clip ViewPager pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819770/do-not-clip-viewpager-pages). While similar, i did not suffer from the NoSaveStateFrameLayout issue the poster had. However in the comment to the accepted answer I found the following tidbit:

> "[...] I had a PageTransformer on my ViewPager, but you couldn't know. I set the layer on my transformed View to NONE, and it worked."

So I tried doing the following in my PageTransformer:

```
public void transformPage(View view, float v) {

    view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
}
```

This finally solved the problem. It should be noted that setting this when creating the element did *not* solve the problem.

Comment: It worked! Soo much thanks! I tried to fix this for 3 days. I had a project where this worked perfect without this line of code and I couldn't find the difference. Now it works but I really don't understand it. Why do I need this line of code? What changes this type while swiping?

Comment: EDIT: I found this line in the other project... one line of code killed me! strange

Comment: THANK. GOD! Had no idea how to fix this.

Comment: where's the love button