# Android TextField to extend over parent fragments bounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My view hierarchy: (left image)

> GreenTextField in RedFragment in BlueFragment in BlackFragment

I need to have the GreenTextField go over parent fragments bounds like the image to the right.
I have tried with negative margin, but I doesn't work.

**Any suggestion about how to solve this?**

This fragments layout is needed and this sample is simplified a lot.

**Result:** As expected this is not really possible.

[image: View layout]

Comment: Have you tried making the GreenTextField a child of the BlackFragment? I'm thinking if you do that, then you can set the GreenTextField bounds based on it. Otherwise, the GreenTextField will be contained in whichever parent it's in.

Comment: That is not an option, because it is only the RedFragment there know here to place it.

Comment: I don't think, with your requirements, that this is possible. Fragment's are like windows - containers for objects. Children objects cannot extend past the bounds of their parents.

Comment: I didn't really expect so either, but I just hoped there might be a hack that could do the trick..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible.

This is not the purpose of fragment(as independent ui element) and fragments' child view can't  exit its parent limits (width and height)...if it is, its a design flaw.

In order to do so you sholud put the black fragment and the textField in a relative layput.

textfield height issues -> change it dynamically on onViewCreated method, of the left red fragment, in order to place it on top of its position.

another solution is to put the textField under the black fragment, and set its position dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

First, if there is a chance to use `ViewGroup`s instead of those nested `Fragment`s, you should think about redesign. It would be crazy to maintain such code :)

But if you really have to keep this structure, try something like that.

1. Set `android:clipChildren="false"` **to all parents** of GreenTextField.
   This works for layouts, but it could not work for Fragments, so see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819770/do-not-clip-viewpager-pages/21926522#21926522).
2. Calculate GreenTextField's **width** and set it (of course programmatically).
3. Make your GreenTextField **draw on top**, over right blue part. There would be no problem if the blue structures are inside `RelativeLayout`, but probably they are not. Then try with `bringChildToFront(View child)` from [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set to the black rect to be a parent of the green. Calculate offset manualy.